# SAPUI5 / OPA5 Tests: How to iterate over several controls

Tags: sapui5, qunit

any idea how i can iterate over a list of controls and for each run the same test?
Example:
I have a generated list of buttons. I want to press each button and check the functionality.
How can I do this?

Starting scenario:

`opaTest("Test if popover is closing.", function (Given, When, Then) {
    Given
        .iStartMyAppInAFrame(linkTestPage);
    When
        .onTheTestPage
        .iPressAButton();
    Then
        .onTheTestPage
        .iShouldSeeTheRequiredAction();
    });`

I need something like that:

`var buttons = readAllButtonsOfList();
    opaTest("Test if popover is closing.", function (Given, When, Then) {
        Given
            .iStartMyAppInAFrame(linkTestPage);
            for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
            {
                When
                    .onTheTestPage
                    .iPressAButton(buttons[i]);
                Then
                    .onTheTestPage
                    .iShouldSeeTheRequiredAction(buttons[i]);
            }
        }
    });`

Hope that anybody can help here.

Answer (score 0):

[OpaDynamicWait](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/core/demokit/sample/OpaDynamicWait/Opa.html) demos recursive action testing, ie while more buttons keep pressing, for a test put an assertion in a success, you can also nest waitfor's